# Why doesn't SpeechSynthesizer work when using SpeechRecognizer?

Tags: ios, swiftui, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

This is clearly a duplicate of several other posts, but all of them are several years old, and none of their solutions work for me.

I am using SpeechSynthesizer and SpeechRecognizer. After a recognition task completes, the SpeechSynthesizer stops producing audible output.

I am using the latest SwiftUI in Xcode 15.2, deploying to an iPhone 14 Pro running iOS 17.3.1.

A couple of the relevant posts are:

[AVSpeechSynthesizer does not speak after using SFSpeechRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270738/avspeechsynthesizer-does-not-speak-after-using-sfspeechrecognizer)

[iOS: AVSpeechSynthesizer doesn't work after recording with SFSpeechRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637714/ios-avspeechsynthesizer-doesnt-work-after-recording-with-sfspeechrecognizer)

Here's my SpeechSynthesizer function:

```
func speak(_ text: String) {
    let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
    utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(identifier: self.appState.chatParameters.voiceIdentifer)
    utterance.rate = 0.5
    speechSynthesizer.speak(utterance)
}
```

And here's the code for setting up the SpeechRecognizer (borrowed from https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/transcribing-audio-text-swiftui-muhammad-asad-chattha):

```
private static func prepareEngine() throws -> (AVAudioEngine, SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest) {
    print("prepareEngine()")
    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
   
    let request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
    request.shouldReportPartialResults = false
    request.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord)
    try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
   
    let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) {
        (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
        request.append(buffer)
    }
    audioEngine.prepare()
    try audioEngine.start()
   
    return (audioEngine, request)
}
```

SpeechSynthesizer works fine as long as I don't call prepareEngine().

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: How are you using the speak function?